# How to make roll animation effect for popup window in android

Tags: android, android-animation

I am developing android application and i am trying to apply some roll effect from top of screen for popup window but  don't know how to achieve but currently i am adding some other animation effect 
this is my popup window function code

```
    private void loadingPopup() {

        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        final View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile_popup, null);

        final PopupWindow windows = new PopupWindow(layout , 450,650,true);
        windows.setFocusable(false);
        windows.setTouchable(true);
        windows.setOutsideTouchable(true);
        windows.setAnimationStyle(R.style.AnimationPopup);
        layout.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                windows.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.TOP, 0, 0);
            }
        });

        name = (TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.name);
        profilepicture =(ImageView)layout.findViewById(R.id.profileimage);

            String  sname = profilelistdb.get(0).get("pname");
            name.setText(sname);
            String imagename =  profilelistdb.get(0).get("pimage");
            String totalurl =  imageurl+imagename;
            imageLoader1.DisplayImage(totalurl, profilepicture);

        btnClosePopup = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.btn_close_popup);
        btnClosePopup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                windows.dismiss();

            }
        });
  }
```

This is **Style.xml**

```
<style name="AnimationPopup">
     <item name="@android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/appear</item>
</style>
```

**appear.xml**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >

        <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:fromYDelta="50%p" android:toYDelta="0%p"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"/>
</set>
```

**My Requirement:-**
     My Popup window should come from top with roll kind of thing and whenever user click close button it should hide popup with reverse roll effect could you please help me how to achieve this.

If you don't understand about what i am trying to say about roll
just check this link and see 30 seconds 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KSHVSswMUng   this is what exactly i need.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this [library](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidViewAnimations). It's for View Animations in android, and works very well. And then use this:

```
YoYo.with(Techniques.RollIn)
    .duration(700)
    .playOn(findViewById(R.id.edit_area));


YoYo.with(Techniques.RollOut)
    .duration(700)
    .playOn(findViewById(R.id.edit_area));
```

Or experiment with it yourself, to see what looks the best.

**Edit:** Not sure how to achieve that particular roll-effect that you have in mind now that I see a video of it, but if you can't find it, I'm sure you'll find something in this library that will look good. Good luck.

Comment: can you tell me after sync this library in our project how can we apply this rollin and rollout effect in popup window

Comment: It's not as you want the effect to be (as in the video), would you still like to get it implemented?

Comment: Actually i am expecting that video effect. if can't,any other way like popup window come from top and when user click close button pop up should dismiss with same effect from bottom to top

Comment: Yes, that is doable with this library. Do you know how to add it into gradle? I'm assuming you're using Android Studio.

Comment: ya i am using android studio and i can add this library to my gradle after that can you edit my code how to apply effect in popup window what ever i ask

Comment: Use it like this: YoYo.with(Techniques.RollIn)
    .duration(700)
    .playOn(findViewById(R.layout.profile_popup)); inside your run method, and let me know what it looks like. Might need to refactor some code.

Comment: it is fine but when i click close button how can i give same effect for dismiss popup